# SharePoint Online Guest User Access

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I've been digging a way to disallow guest users from seen other members in the same O365 group. No luck so far. Is there any way to add guest members to a group and don't let them know about each other inclusion?

To clarify my point, I have an extranet site which has a documento library with custom permissions and I need to allow all my clients (external users/guests) to access this extranet site but not let them know about other clients allowed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide *all* members from each other using `New-UnifiedGroup -HiddenGroupMembershipEnabled $true`, though this cannot be set on an existing Group.

I would strongly suggest a re-architecture. Create a Group (thus SharePoint site) per client. This provides the separation you're after.

Comment: thanks! I'll try that out and let you know

Comment: mmm...  Maybe it's not exactly what I'm looking for. Here's the definition of this switch extracted from MS Docs: _______

-HiddenGroupMembershipEnabled
The HiddenGroupMembershipEnabled switch specifies whether to hide the members of the Office 365 Group from users who aren't members of the group. You don't need to specify a value with this switch. _______

I actually need to hide the members from the members. I mean, don't let the member to know who are the other members.

Comment: Per the docs, you can't enable that setting _after_ creating the Group. it must be done via PoSh with the New- cmdlet. But I'd strongly suggest rethinking the architecture to prevent mistakes and data leakage.

Comment: This does not actually help, because a member can open the share panel and type any name and "see" the other from the picker.

Comment: This is more or less the only option available.